# Phantomjs fails when Protractor is run with selenium hub

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor

I have a protractor config file as follows and i use phantomjs to run the tests. It works when i use `seleniumServerJar` but fails when i use `seleniumAddress` (pointing to a hub) with a 'The driver executable does not exist' message! Is there any specific config to run phantomjs with selenium-hub?

```
exports.config = {

   //Fails when i use this
  //seleniumAddress:"http://selenium-hub.com:4659/wd/hub",
//Works when i use this selenium-standalone jar
seleniumServerJar: '../../../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',

  framework: 'cucumber',
  specs: [
'features/*.feature'
  ],


  capabilities: {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "phantomjs.binary.path": require("phantomjs").path,
        "phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args": ["--loglevel=DEBUG"]
  },

  baseUrl: '',

  rootElement: 'body',

  resultJsonOutputFile: 'src/test/report.json',

  cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'features/steps/*_steps.js',
        }

};
```